# KOMA-Script throws "! Extra \else" error

Tags: errors, koma-script

With a minimal document such as

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

I am getting the following error with **`latex filename.tex`**

```
! Extra \else.
\@sect ...sname }{\scr@ds@tocentry }\fi \fi \else 
                                              \def \@svsechd {#6{\hskip ...
l.49 \section{Introduction}
```

Can anyone help pinpoint where the problem might be?

- If I change the document class to be article, it works fine
- If I remove the \pagestyle{headings}, it works fine
- If I change headings to empty, it works fine

Versions:

```
pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Arch Linux)
kpathsea version 6.1.1
...
Compiled with libpng 1.6.10; using libpng 1.6.10
Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
Compiled with poppler version 0.24.5
```

and KOMA-Script (`scrartcl.cls`)

```
%%% From File: $Id: scrkernel-version.dtx 1560 2013-12-19 07:13:30Z mjk $
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just as addition to [Gonzalo’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/166780/9237). You’ve run into a known bug of KOMA-Script version 3.12.

Cf. (alas only in German) [Bekannte Probleme und Änderungen in KOMA-Script 3.12](http://komascript.de/release3.12):

> ```
> scrartcl:
> […]
> Wenn man den Seitenstil headings aktiviert, wird man mit Fehlern wegen eines \fi zu viel
> bombadiert.
> Workaround: Paket scrlayer-scrpage (oder notfalls scrpage2) laden und Seitenstil
> scrheadings verwenden.
> Hinweis: Der Fehler ist in der experimentellen Release behoben.
> ```

It means that the error you observed is removed in an experimental version you can download from a page, which is linked behind the words “experimentellen Release”, but is again in German. Fortunately Markus Kohm created for this page an English companion: [Using most current KOMA-Script with TeX Live, MacTeX or MiKTeX](http://komascript.de/node/1801).

Without using this experimental version you should load the (KOMA-Script) package `scrlayer-scrpage` and use the pagestyle `scrheadings`, similar like Gonzalo suggested. *(In my eyes with version 3.12 there is no need anymore for using package `scrpage2`, because `scrlayer-scrpage` is downwards compatible, as long as you never have used internal commands of `scrpage2`.)*

Answer (score 8):

As [Speravir's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/166786/3954) points out, this is a bug; the `headings` page style *should* work with KOMA classes. A possible work-around is to load the `scrpage2` package and change to `useheadings` style:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{useheadings}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Page 206 of the `scrguien` document mentions this:

> The package `scrpage2` is meant primarily for use of the supplied styles
>   or for defining one’s own styles. However, it may be necessary to
>   shift back also to a style provided by the docu- ment class. It might
>   appear that this should be done with `\pagestyle{headings}`, but this
>   has the disadvantage that commands `\automark` and `\manualmark`, to be
>   discussed shortly, do not function as expected. For this reason one
>   should shift back to the original styles using
>   v\pagestyle{useheadings}`, which chooses the correct page styles
>   automatically for both manual and automatic running headings.

Comment: @Speravir Thank you. I agree this answer shouldn't be deleted but also that it should be edited to make clear that the use of `headings` *should be* perfectly appropriate but that it doesn't work due to a bug. Would either of you care to comment on the code in my answer? This seems to work but I don't know if it is the right way to fix it or not. Unfortunately, I don't read German either...

Comment: @cfr you're answer seems to be right, but I cannot say for sure; I am not familar with the "KOMA way" of doing things.

Comment: That's my worry, too. I don't use these classes myself. I really just followed the error and compared with the other places using the same macro. (e.g. `\MakeMarkcase` for `section` and `subsection` below.) This is why I expanded the MWE a bit. (Actually, I added a bunch more but didn't want to post the entire thing as it seemed to work.) But that is hardly rigorous testing!

Comment: Excellent stuff guys! Thanks everyone for the detailed responses: a workaround and a hack. You guys rock

Comment: @Mack: Then apart from accepting Gonzalo’s answer give an upvote to all, too. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

The use of `headings` produces the following error:

```
! Extra \else.
\@sect ...sname }{\scr@ds@tocentry }\fi \fi \else 
                                                  \def \@svsechd {#6{\hskip ...
l.6 \section{Introduction}

?
```

As explained in Speravir's answer, this is a bug in the current (non-experimental) version of the class. If you prefer to use the standard `headings` in preference to the workaround in Gonzalo Medina's answer, you might like to try the following fix.

## Fixing the definition of `headings`

The following redefinition appears to solve the problem. The line marked `MODIFIED` contains an extra `\fi` in the original which is not present in other uses of `\MakeMarkcase`. The fix modifies that line to remove the `\fi` in line with other uses of the macro.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand*{\ps@headings}{\let\@mkboth\markboth
    \renewcommand*{\@evenhead}{%
      \set@tempdima@hw\hss\hb@xt@ \@tempdima{\vbox{%
          \hb@xt@ \@tempdima{{\headfont\strut\leftmark\hfil}}%
          \if@hsl \vskip 1.5\p@ \hrule \fi}}}%
    \renewcommand*{\@oddhead}{%
      \set@tempdima@hw\hb@xt@ \@tempdima{\vbox{%
          \hb@xt@ \@tempdima{{\headfont\hfil\strut\rightmark
              \if@twoside\else\hfil\fi}}%
          \if@hsl \vskip 1.5\p@ \hrule \fi}}\hss}%
    \renewcommand*{\@evenfoot}{%
      \set@tempdima@hw\hss\hb@xt@ \@tempdima{\vbox{%
          \if@fsl \hrule \vskip 3\p@ \fi
          \hb@xt@ \@tempdima{{\pagemark\hfil}}}}}%
    \renewcommand*{\@oddfoot}{%
      \set@tempdima@hw\hb@xt@ \@tempdima{\vbox{%
          \if@fsl \hrule \vskip 3\p@ \fi
          \hb@xt@ \@tempdima{{\hfil\pagemark
              \if@twoside\else\hfil\fi}}}}\hss}%
    \renewcommand*{\sectionmark}[1]{%
      \if@twoside\expandafter\markboth\else\expandafter\markright\fi
      {\MakeMarkcase{\ifnumbered{section}{\sectionmarkformat}{}##1}}{}}% MODIFIED
    \renewcommand*{\subsectionmark}[1]{%
      \if@twoside
        \markright{%
          \MakeMarkcase{\ifnumbered{subsection}{\subsectionmarkformat}{}##1}%
        }%
      \fi
    }%
  }%
\makeatother
\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\kant[1]
\subsection{Subsection}
\kant[2]
\section{Another Section}
\kant[3]
\section{Yet Another Section}
\kant[4]
\subsection{Another Subsection}
\kant[5]
\end{document}
```

## The result

[image: headings]

Comment: I’m not that good to decide, whether you made something “wrong” (obviously it is a working patch at least for your example code). But if you’re lazy you could download the experimental resource and compare how Markus Kohm fixed it himself (but note, there are other fixed bugs, too).

Answer (score 4):

As has already been explained this is a bug of `KOMA 3.12` which is known to the developers since late December 2013 and fixed in an experimental release. As I encountered myself the bug early January, I had to patch it for my own sources and here is my patch:

```
\pagestyle{headings}% must be before the patch
\makeatletter
\def\buggysectionmark #1{% KOMA 3.12 as released to CTAN December 2013
    \if@twoside\expandafter\markboth\else\expandafter\markright\fi
    {\MakeMarkcase{\ifnumbered{section}{\sectionmarkformat\fi}{}#1}}{}}
\ifx\buggysectionmark\sectionmark
\def\sectionmark #1{%
    \if@twoside\expandafter\markboth\else\expandafter\markright\fi
    {\MakeMarkcase{\ifnumbered{section}{\sectionmarkformat}{}#1}}{}}
\fi
\makeatother
```

The idea is that once your installation has the next release of `KOMAscript` where this problem will have been fixed, the patch will do nothing (because the `\ifx` test will detect that `\sectionmark` is not the buggy one anymore) and the patch will do nothing you don't have to fiddle again with your legacy sources.